# Resultados diferentes en Valgrind

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en C y uno de los requisitos que impone el enunciado es que no presente leaks de memoria ni data races. En casa trabajo en una raspberry pi 400 y en clase, que es donde tenemos que entregarlo, usamos iMacs. En ambos lugares tengo instalado Valgrind. El caso es que la detección de leaks coincide en que no hay ninguno pero en cuanto a los data races (usando Helgrind) en casa me dice que no hay ninguno y sin embargo en clase me aparecen a montones. ¿A qué se puede deber esto? En casa he confirmado que no hay data races comprobándolo también con TSan (-fsanitize=thread).
Gracias.

Comment: Es posible que tengas algún comportamiento indeterminado en tu código. La forma en la que éstos se convierten a binario depende del compilador. Así, la solución propuesta por dos compiladores diferentes puede arrojar resultados distintos en valgrind ... esto es solo una suposición, ya que no has enseñado ni tan siquiera un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema

Comment: Sin ver el código no podemos ayudarte. El tema de las data races se produce cuando dos hilos compiten por acceder o modificar la misma información.

Comment: Gracias a ambos